# MD5/SHA Field Dataset in Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I need to concatanate a few string values in order to obtain the SHA256 encrypted string. I've seen Data Fusion has a plugin to do the job:

[image]

The documentation however is very poor and nothing I've tried seems to work. I created a table in BQ with the string fields I need to concatanate but the output is same as input. Can anyone provide with an example on how to use this plugin?

EDIT

Below I present the example,

This is how the workflow looks like:

[image]

For the testing purposes, I added one column with the following string:

```
2022-01-01T00:00:00+01:00
```

[image]

And here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wrangler](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/targeting-campaign-pipeline) to concatenate the string values.

I tried your scenario adding Wrangler to the Pipeline:

[image]

Joining 2 Columns:
[image]

I named the column `new_col`, using `,` as delimiter:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This part I do understand, however nothing is happening when it comes to hashing the concatenated sting itselft. Can you show me the configuration of the MD5/SHA plugin and the outcome of such operation?

Comment: For the specific behavior of MD5/SHA plugin, you can raise the ticket in this [link](https://cdap.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/CDAP/issues)

Answer (score 0):

What you described can be achieved by 2 Wranglers:

1. The first Wrangler will be what @angela-b described. Use the [merge directive](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/382140577/Merge+directive) to create a new column with the concatenation of two columns. Example directive that joins column `a` and `b` using `,` as the delimiter and stores the result in column `a_b`:

```
merge a b a_b ,
```

2. The second Wrangler will use the [hash directive](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/382140542/Hash+directive) which will hash the column in place using a specified algorithm. Example of a directive that hashes column `a_b` using MD5:

```
hash :a_b 'MD5' true
```

Remember to set the last parameter `encode` to true so that you get a string output instead of a byte array.